# Process Dropbox folders and files from an external app

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'd like to automate a process whereby a client can place lots of files into Dropbox, and then I can read all the files from Dropbox and create database entries for each file/folder within the client's CMS.  The CMS is a C# .NET MVC app with lots of client-side javascript.  What are my options for tapping into Dropbox from either C# or javascript?  Has anyone integrated a C# web app with Dropbox in this way?  Can I use the REST api from C# or js?

If this works I'd like to automate the process for many clients, and make Dropbox an integral part of the CMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the REST API from C# and it's the best way to go; you kind of answered yourself.

Comment: Thanks - Can I also use it from a .js context or would I hit cross-site scripting issues?

Comment: Respectively yes and no: REST uses HTTP requests, so there is no difference in using Ajax or any other way and there are no XSS issues. Still, it may be a better idea to use a server-side solution (for example, for security and compatibility reasons).

Comment: When I try an initial ajax request from js I get the following error XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token. Origin http://localhost:56642 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Does this not indicate an XSS issue?

Comment: Yup, I supposed DropBox supported Access-Control-Allow-Origin but it's not the case; you can still use JSONP, but you can't upload files with (no POST).